# How to map with FluentNHibernate N:N Relationship with additional attribute

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this database model:

Candidato 1<->N Telefone N<->1 TipoTelefone

Where my tables has those columns

## Candidato

- Id (int - identity)
- NomeCompleto
- DataNascimento

## Telefone

- Id (int - identity)
- IdCandidato
- IdTipoTelefone
- Numero

## TipoTelefone

- Id (int - identity)
- Nome

My classes properties are:

```
Candidato
=========
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }

Telefone
========
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual Candidato Candidato { get; set; }
public virtual TipoTelefone TipoTelefone { get; set; }
public virtual string Numero { get; set; }

TipoTelefone
============
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
public IList<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
```

I am trying to save a Candidato and its Telefones, cause I have one Candidato for Many Telefones.

But I am getting errors, when I try to save at the same time my Candidato and its Telefones. Below there are some errors that I am getting every time I try some kind of attempt:

- object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: Entity.Telefone, Entity: Entity.Telefone
- object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging: Entity.Telefone
- The class has no identifier property: Entity.Telefone
- Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Telefone' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
- Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[Entity.Telefone]' no tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Entity.Telefone]'.
- object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: Entity.Telefone, Entity: Entity.Telefone
- could not insert: [Entity.Telefone][SQL: INSERT INTO Telefone (Numero, IdTipoTelefone, Id) VALUES (?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

My project is using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode but I am suspecting that I am not getting the right map solution with it. So, I would like to know, how to make the correct mapping, for those three entities.

Is important to see that my N:N Telefone table has a property Numero, so this entity/table is not a simple N:N entity, but a real entity cause it has a own property inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old example I have.

This is my "middle" table.

Here is a fluent-map

```
public class EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkMap : ClassMap<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkNHEntity>
{

    public EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkMap()
    {

        Schema("dbo");
        Table("EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink");

        Id(x => x.LinkSurrogateUUID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.PriorityRank);
        Map(x => x.JobStartedOnDate);

        References(x => x.TheEmployee).Column("TheEmployeeUUID").Not.Nullable().Index("IX_ETJTMLM_TheEmployeeUUID_And_TheJobTitleUUID"); ;/*Bad naming convention with "The", but left here so it can be seen easily in the DDL*/
        References(x => x.TheJobTitle).Column("TheJobTitleUUID").Not.Nullable().Index("IX_ETJTMLM_TheEmployeeUUID_And_TheJobTitleUUID"); ;/*Bad naming convention with "The", but left here so it can be seen easily in the DDL*/

    }
}
```

Here is (I think the same as above) as a hbm.xml file.

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" schema="dbo" name="MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Data.NHibernateSetup.Domain.EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkNHEntity, MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Data.NHibernateSetup, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink">
    <id name="LinkSurrogateUUID" type="System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="LinkSurrogateUUID" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="PriorityRank" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="PriorityRank" />
    </property>
    <property name="JobStartedOnDate" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="JobStartedOnDate" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Data.NHibernateSetup.Domain.EmployeeNHEntity, MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Data.NHibernateSetup, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="TheEmployee">
      <column name="TheEmployeeUUID" index="IX_ETJTMLM_TheEmployeeUUID_And_TheJobTitleUUID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Data.NHibernateSetup.Domain.JobTitleNHEntity, MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Data.NHibernateSetup, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="TheJobTitle">
      <column name="TheJobTitleUUID" index="IX_ETJTMLM_TheEmployeeUUID_And_TheJobTitleUUID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

PriorityRank and JobStartedOnDate would be my "extra attributes on the relationship".

Here is another hbm.xml file I found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Glue"
                   namespace="MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Glue.Domain">

  <class name="EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink" lazy="false" schema="MySchema">

    <!-- Naming this "Id" might be a requirement, be careful -->


    <!-- 
      ISSUE If the generator class is changed from "assigned" to 
      guid
      guid.comb
      uuid.string

      It will break the ability to create the relationship

    -->


    <id name="LinkSurrogateUUID">
      <generator class="guid.comb"></generator>
    </id>

    <!-- 
    <id name="LinkSurrogateKey">
      <!- -
      <generator class="hilo">
            <param name="table">HiloHolder</param>
        <param name="column">HiloColumn</param>
      </generator>
      - ->
      <generator class="identity">
      </generator>
    </id>
    -->

    <many-to-one name="TheEmployee" column="EmployeeUUID" lazy="false" cascade="none" not-null="true" /> <!-- class="MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Glue.Domain.Employee, MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Glue" -->
    <many-to-one name="TheJobTitle" column="JobTitleUUID" lazy="false" cascade="none" not-null="true" /> <!-- class="MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Glue.Domain.JobTitle, MyCompany.MyTechnology.Prototypes.CompositeAppPOC.Glue" -->

    <!-- 
    <many-to-one name="TheEmployee" column="EmployeeKey" lazy="false" cascade="none" not-null="true" /> 
    <many-to-one name="TheJobTitle" column="JobTitleKey" lazy="false" cascade="none" not-null="true" /> 
    -->

    <!-- These are "scalar properties of the ~relationship~"-->
    <property name="PriorityRank" not-null="true" update="false"  />
    <property name="JobStartedOnDate" not-null="true" update="false" />

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my "middle" domain object

```
[Serializable]
public partial class EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink
{
    public EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink()
    {
        //this.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); /* this works in conjuction with <generator class="assigned"></generator>   */
    }


    //EF Tweaks
    public Guid TheEmployeeUUID { get; set; }
    public Guid TheJobTitleUUID { get; set; }

    public Guid? LinkSurrogateUUID { get; set; }

    /*  These are "scalar properties of the ~~relationship~~  */
    public int PriorityRank { get; set; }
    public DateTime JobStartedOnDate { get; set; }

    public Employee TheEmployee { get; set; }
    public JobTitle TheJobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe that can help.

I solved this at one point, but its been several years now.

The key is that you have a domain object that has the extra scalars AND a single object for each "side".

```
Telefone
========
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual Candidato Candidato { get; set; }
public virtual TipoTelefone TipoTelefone { get; set; }
public virtual string Numero { get; set; }
```

I believe you have this correct with your Telefone class.  So I think the issue is your mapping.  Fluent or hbm.xml.  Maybe my "notes" can help.  I couldn't put this in the comments.

There was some voodoo I had to do with adding the "middle" object to either "outer" object.

For example:

```
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Employee 
    {

        public Employee()
        {
            CommonConstructor();
        }
        private void CommonConstructor()
        {
            this.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkCollection();
        }



        //EF Tweaks
        public Guid ParentDepartmentUUID { get; set; }


        public Guid? EmployeeUUID { get; set; }

        public byte[] TheVersionProperty { get; set; }

        //public int? EmployeeKey { get; set; }



//        public IDepartment ParentDepartment { get; set; }

        public string SSN { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        //



        public EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkCollection MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks { get; set; }




        public void AddJobTitleLink(EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link)
        {
            link.TheEmployee = this;
            if (!this.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                this.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Add(link);
            }

            if (!link.TheJobTitle.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                link.TheJobTitle.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Add(link);
            }
        }

        public void RemoveJobTitleLink(EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link)
        {
            link.TheEmployee = this;
            if (this.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                this.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Remove(link);
            }

            if (link.TheJobTitle.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                link.TheJobTitle.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Remove(link);
            }
        }











        //public ICollection<IParkingAreaDeprecated> MyParkingAreas { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<ParkingArea> MyParkingAreas { get; set; }
        public IParkingAreaCollection MyParkingAreas { get; set; }





        //public void AddParkingArea(IParkingAreaDeprecated pa)
        public void AddParkingArea(ParkingArea pa)
        {
            //pa.MyEmployees.Add(this);
            if (!pa.MyEmployees.Contains(this))
            {
                //pa.AddEmployee(this);//Causes overflow situation
                pa.MyEmployees.Add(this);
            }
            if (!this.MyParkingAreas.Contains(pa))
            {
                this.MyParkingAreas.Add(pa);
            }
        }

        //public void RemoveParkingArea(IParkingAreaDeprecated pa)
        public void RemoveParkingArea(ParkingArea pa)
        {
            if (pa.MyEmployees.Contains(this))
            {
                pa.MyEmployees.Remove(this);
            }
            if (this.MyParkingAreas.Contains(pa))
            {
                this.MyParkingAreas.Remove(pa);
            }
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
           return string.Format("{0}:{1},{2}", this.SSN , this.LastName , this.FirstName );
        }



    }




}
```

and the other "outer" object

```
   [Serializable]
    public partial class JobTitle : IJobTitle
    {

        public JobTitle()
        {
            CommonConstructor();
        }
        private void CommonConstructor()
        {
            //this.MyEmployees = new List<Employee>();
            //this.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks = new List<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink>();
            this.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkCollection();
        }

        public Guid? JobTitleUUID { get; set; }
        //public int? JobTitleKey { get; set; }


        //public byte[] TheVersionProperty { get; set; }


        public string JobTitleName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        //public ICollection<Employee> MyEmployees { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<IEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink> MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink> MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks { get; set; }
        public IEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinkCollection MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks { get; set; }


        public void AddEmployeeLink(EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link)
        {
            link.TheJobTitle = this;
            if (!this.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                this.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Add(link);
            }

            if (!link.TheEmployee.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                link.TheEmployee.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Add(link);
            }

        }

        public void RemoveEmployeeLink(EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link)
        {
            link.TheJobTitle = this;
            if (this.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                this.MyJobTitleToEmployeeMatchLinks.Remove(link);
            }

            if (link.TheEmployee.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Contains(link))
            {
                link.TheEmployee.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks.Remove(link);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my code where I wire up everything.

Note, I have a Department entity I've not discussed before.
The important parts is the Employee, the JobTitle and the "link" object

```
            EmployeeController empRepo = null;
            JobTitleController jtRepo = null;

            Department idept = new Department() { DepartmentName = "Department One", CreateDate = DateTime.Now };
            DepartmentController deptRepo = new DepartmentController();
            deptRepo.Add(idept);

            Employee emp = new Employee() { ParentDepartment = idept, SSN = "111111111", CreateDate = DateTime.Now, HireDate = DateTime.Now, LastName = "Smith", FirstName = "John" };
            JobTitle jtDev = new JobTitle() { JobTitleName = "Developer", CreateDate = DateTime.Now };
            JobTitle jtProjectManager = new JobTitle() { JobTitleName = "Project Manager", CreateDate = DateTime.Now };
            JobTitle jtDba = new JobTitle() { JobTitleName = "DBA", CreateDate = DateTime.Now };

            jtRepo = new JobTitleController();
            jtRepo.Add(jtDev);
            jtRepo.Add(jtProjectManager);

            empRepo = new EmployeeController();
            empRepo.AddEmployee(emp);

            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link1ToAddThruJobTitleObject = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link1ToAddThruJobTitleObject.TheEmployee = emp;
            link1ToAddThruJobTitleObject.TheJobTitle = jtDba;
            link1ToAddThruJobTitleObject.JobStartedOnDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            link1ToAddThruJobTitleObject.PriorityRank = 5;

            jtDba.AddEmployeeLink(link1ToAddThruJobTitleObject);

            jtRepo.Add(jtDba);

            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link1ToAddThruEmployeeObject = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link1ToAddThruEmployeeObject.TheEmployee = emp;
            link1ToAddThruEmployeeObject.TheJobTitle = jtDev;
            link1ToAddThruEmployeeObject.JobStartedOnDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
            link1ToAddThruEmployeeObject.PriorityRank = 1;

            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link2ToAddThruEmployeeObject = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link2ToAddThruEmployeeObject.TheEmployee = emp;
            link2ToAddThruEmployeeObject.TheJobTitle = jtProjectManager;
            link2ToAddThruEmployeeObject.JobStartedOnDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5);
            link2ToAddThruEmployeeObject.PriorityRank = 2;

            emp.AddJobTitleLink(link1ToAddThruEmployeeObject);
            emp.AddJobTitleLink(link2ToAddThruEmployeeObject);

            empRepo.Upsert(emp);
```

Comment: And @granadaCoder how is the correct way to insert this entities ??? Could you show me an example of the command to save a candidate and 2 telefones, for example ?

Comment: I appended the answer.  Now I remember some voodoo about getting all the objects to line up.....when you add the middleobject to either of the outer objects.  See my Add and Remove "Link" methods above.

Comment: Hi @granadaCoder...Thanks so much for your help. One question about your code... Are your EmployeeControlles and JobTitleController where you have the NHibernate Add Method ?

Comment: That code is very trivial "NHibernate" code.   example:          public void Add(JobTitleNHEntity jt)
        {
            using (ISession session = ISessionCreator.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(jt);
                transaction.Commit();
            }

Comment: Maybe you can pick up some hints from here:  http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/02/fluent-nhbernate-and-collections.html

Comment: Let me ask you other thing... in your logic, you are including 3 new "links", 1 to join emp - jtdbs, 2 to join emp - jtdev and 3 to join emp - jtprojectmanager. But your voodoo method jtDba.AddEmployeeLink is used just once and the emp.AddJobTitleLink is used twice. My question is if the correct would be call those Add Methods from outside entities three times (each one) before persisting

Comment: i don't remember.  i think i was trying to add one "link" from the jobtitle side, and two "links" from the emp side...as I look at the code.  This is from 3 years ago....so my memory is fuzzy.  I know I got it working at some point because i teared up a little.

Comment: Hi my friend @granadaCoder, your help was crucial for my success !!! I made my project persists the Candidato and its Telefones successfully. Thanks so much man !!!

Comment: Just one comment... I only needed to do the "voodoo" on the parent outer entity. It was not needed to use the "voodoo" Add method on the child entity TipoTelefone

Comment: Great.  To followup, please post the relevant portions of your wokring code at the end of your original question with some identification like "my working solution".  So future readers can learn from your question.  Second, if you have it working, then please mark one of the answer(s) here as "the answer" so this question does not keep coming up as "unanswered" in the SOF queries.

Comment: For future readers, Olivertech is probably only adding the "voodoo" to one side because he probably starts the object-building from that side.  In my code, I was trying to build the object-model from either side......which is why I had special "addlink" methods on each side.  It'll depend on your need.