# Fluent Nhibernate Many to many with a pk and fk in one table

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, many-to-many, fluent-nhibernate

Hey i have the following mysql tables:

[image]

and i have the following maping classes:

```
 public class WalletMap : ClassMap<Wallet>
    {
        public WalletMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.wallet_id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.amount);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.users).Inverse().Cascade.All().Table("User_has_Wallet");
            References(x => x.currency);


        }
    }
```

```
 public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Id(x=>x.user_id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.firstname);
            Map(x => x.lastname);
            Map(x => x.birthday);
            Map(x => x.email);
            Map(x => x.password);
            Map(x => x.creditcardnumber);
            Map(x => x.country);
            Map(x => x.street);
            Map(x => x.housenumber);
            Map(x => x.zipcode);
            Map(x => x.telephonenumber);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.wallets).Cascade.All().Table("User_has_Wallet");





        }
    }
```

the error says "MySqlException: Field 'currency_id' doesn't have a default value",
does somebody has an idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Because you have a "attribute on the RELATIONSHIP", you cannot "get by" with 2 entities.  You have to create a third entity .. which is based on the RELATIONSHIP.  You can find some hints by looking at this object ("EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink") at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200860/214977

Answer (score 0):

When you have a relationship between 2 entities, there are 2 modes of that relationship.

```
Painting
Color
PaintingToColorLink
```

"Simple".

Your "middle" aka "link" table has ONLY 2 columns.

In the above situation..... the PaintingToColorLink table will have ONLY 2 columns.

```
PaintingKey
ColorKey
```

again ONLY 2 columns.

..

Or your M:N relationship is "complex"

```
Employee
  long EmployeeKey

JobTitle
  long JobTitleKey

EmployeeToJobTitleLink
  long EmployeeToJobTitleLinkKey
  long EmployeeKey
  long JobTitleKey
  int PriorityRank
  DateTime JobStartedOnDate
```

So Mary may be a "software developer", but she (specifically only her) started on 01/01/2021.

And John may also be a "software developer", but he (specifically only him) started on 02/02/2022.

The JobStartedOnDate is a property of the RELATIONSHIP.  It doesn't belong to the JobTitle only (not everyone starts being a software-developer on the date).....nor does it belong on the Employee (I do not start every job-title I have on the same date necessarily).

When you have a "complex" M:N, you must add this "relationship entity" to your Entity-Models and your mappings.

In my example, you need this class defined:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink
{

 
    public long TheEmployeeForeignKey { get; set; }
    public long TheJobTitleForeignKey { get; set; }

    public long EmployeeToJobTitleLinkKey { get; set; }

    /*  These are "scalar properties of the ~~relationship~~  */
    public int PriorityRank { get; set; }
    public DateTime JobStartedOnDate { get; set; }

    public Employee TheEmployee { get; set; }
    public JobTitle TheJobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

...

In your case, you need to create this "middle" relationship object.... and an Orm-Map for it.

```
public class UserToWalletLink

  public int UserId {get;set}

  public int WalletId {get;set}

  public User TheUser {get;set}

  public Wallet TheWallet  {get;set}
 
  public int CurrencyId  {get;set}

  /* it CurrencyId is FK to another table, then you need
    public Currency TheCurrency  {get;set} 
  as well */
```